# ASP.NET Eval Byte Array as String

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, arrays, eval

I am building a ListView from an EntityDataSource. There is a Byte[] field called Sha1Hash that I need to convert to a String type for a Hyperlink. This is a code snippet from ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl_Document" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/GetDocument.ashx?docId={0}", Eval("SHA1HASH") ) %>' 
    Text='<%# Eval("DOCUMENTNAME") %>' />
```

This is producing a URL like "~/GetDocument.ashx?docId=System.Byte[]", but it needs to be a hex string representing the value of the byte array. What would be the best approach to accomplish this? Ideally I would accomplish this entirely in the .aspx page rather than the code behind.

Update: I resolved this issue by using

```
NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/GetDocument.ashx?docId={0}", BitConverter.ToString((byte[])Eval("SHA1HASH")).Replace("-", string.Empty) ) %>'
```

My problem was that I needed to cast Eval() to byte[]. It was being cast to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using

```
NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/GetDocument.ashx?docId={0}", BitConverter.ToString((byte[])Eval("SHA1HASH")).Replace("-", string.Empty) ) %>'
```

My problem was that I needed to cast Eval() to byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what format you want, you're probably looking for `Convert.ToBase64String()` or `BitConverter.ToHexString()`.